# Quartz2D for OSX not drawing anything

Tags: cocoa, graphics, quartz-2d

I'm trying to draw to the screen, but it's not working. I think I'm missing some connection. The biggest problem is I find a million and one iOS tutorials, but nothing for Mac OSX! Very frustrating. The screenshots show how I have my project set up...I'm using XCode 5.

[image: Created a custom view]

I created a class called MyQuartzView which is a subclass of NSView. Here's the listing for what I have in MyQuartzView.m:

```
#import "MyQuartzView.h"

@implementation MyQuartzView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    // Drawing code here.
    CGContextRef myContext = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
    NSLog(@"%@", myContext);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myContext, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextFillRect (myContext, CGRectMake (0, 0, 200, 100 ));
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myContext, 0, 0, 1, .5);
    CGContextFillRect (myContext, CGRectMake (0, 0, 100, 200));
}

@end
```

I do not have any code in MyQuartzView.h.

I'm stuck...please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. I just forgot to connect my custom view that I dragged onto my window to my MyQuartzView class via the "Identity Inspector" in the interface portion of Xcode.